# C# Falha ao enviar e-mails utilizando SmtpClient

Tags: c#, envio-de-email, smtp

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro ao executar o sistema no servidor com a porta 587:
*Caixa de correio não disponível*

Stack de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando troco a porta para a 465 e *SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;* ocorre timeout;

Executo o mesmo sistema na minha máquina local e funciona normalmente com a porta 587.

Código fonte utilizado:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("host");
mail.From = new MailAddress("email");
mail.To.Add("to");
mail.Subject = "teste"
mail.Body = "teste";

SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new 
System.Net.NetworkCredential("login", "senha");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: pode ser um problema de firewall, mas pela parte de mansagem que dá para ler, parece que você não está autenticando com a mesma conta de e-mail que está utilizando para enviar a mensagem.

Comment: Testei com o firewall desativado e o erro persistiu.